# How to write strings and integers in a ring buffer?

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

How to write strings and integers in a ring buffer? I would like to write multiple strings and integers into the ring buffer but my c++ knowledge is limited. If you need some more info, please let me know. I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Here are the integer and string variables that I want to write and the write function of the ring buffer:

```
string payload;
int byte_pos;

size_t ringbuffer::write(u_char *data, size_t bytes)
{
  if (bytes == 0) return 0;

  size_t capacity = capacity_;
  size_t bytes_to_write = std::min(bytes, capacity - size_);

  // Write in a single step
  if (bytes_to_write <= capacity - end_index_)
  {
    memcpy(data_ + end_index_, data, bytes_to_write);
    end_index_ += bytes_to_write;
    if (end_index_ == capacity) end_index_ = 0;
  }
  // Write in two steps
  else
  {
    size_t size_1 = capacity - end_index_;
    memcpy(data_ + end_index_, data, size_1);
    size_t size_2 = bytes_to_write - size_1;
    memcpy(data_, data + size_1, size_2);
    end_index_ = size_2;
  }

  size_ += bytes_to_write;
  return bytes_to_write;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question: what is it you want to do? Just call this function with your given inputs?

Comment: Yes, I can't get the arguments right. I tried with (payload, sizeof(payload)) for example and also many other things but I always get invalid arguments. So my question is how to call the function once for the string and once for the integer. Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: Is it a "buffer of (strings and numbers)" or a "buffer of (strings or numbers)"? You would use a `struct` or `union`, respectively. The code example shown is quite incomplete and lacks comments on how it is supposed to work. To me it looks much more like some mess (like assembly language using C++ syntax) rather than a ring buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your `std::string` variable into a C-style pointer to char:

```
string payload;
char* cpayload = payload.c_str();
int len = strlen(cpayload);
ringbuffer::write(cpayload, len*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Invalid arguments
Candidates are:
unsigned int write(unsigned char *, unsigned int)

Comment: Then cast the `len`: `unsigned int len = (unsigned int) strlen(cpayload) * sizeof(char)` and use `len` as the second argument.

Comment: Still not working mate but I think I found out what is the problem. If you are interested you can check my answer, thank you for your attention to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to be working but I haven't verified what exactly I am getting in the ringbuffer yet, no errors though.

```
ringbuffer::write((u_char*) payload.c_str(), payload.length());
ringbuffer::write((u_char*) &byte_pos, sizeof(byte_pos));
```